# Trouble with a proof: $(p^n - 1 , e)=1$ for $e\in \mathbb{N}$, p prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm having trouble understanding a proof. The Lemma states:
***For every natural number $e$ there are infinitely many prime powers $q$ with $(q-1,e)=1$***.
The prove is as follows:
 
Write $e=2^km$, m odd. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
The number $2^n$ is a unit modulo $m$ $\rightarrow$ why??? 
and hence there are infinitely many $n$ such that $2^n \equiv1modulo\; m$.
Replacing $n$ by $n+1$ we get $2^n \equiv 2modulo\; m$
hence $2^n-1 \equiv 1modulo \; m$, the lemma follows.
The only step I don't understand is the previous why???
Did the author intend to say: choose an $n$ such that $2^n\equiv 1modulo\;m$?? or "unit modulo m" means something that I'm not catching because of poor number theory background? (just want to make sure :) ) 
The article is here: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605429
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number $u\in \mathbb{Z}$ is a unit modulo $m$ if there exists $v\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
u\cdot v\equiv 1\pmod m.
$$
If you know ring theory then this definition is equivalent to $\overline{u}$ being a unit in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. You can show that $u$ is a unit modulo $m$ if and only if the greatest common divisor of $u$ and $m$ is $1$. Hence in the above proof 2 is a unit modulo $m$. Any power of a unit is again a unit (why?), so $2^n$ is a unit modulo $m$ for all $n$. There are infinitely many $n$ such that $2^n \equiv 1 \pmod m$ and for each such $n$, $q=2^n$ satisfies the statement of the lemma.

Let me know if you have questions on the last two lines and I can help you with that.

Comment: Before your answer I was having trouble with the last lines but now everything is crystal clear. Thank you!